# Latin square and why it's not a group

Tags: group-theory, latin-square

I'm working on this question about Latin Squares

> Explain why the following Latin Square isn't the multiplication table of a group.

Here is the table:

$$\begin{array}{c|ccccc}
 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
\hline
1& 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
2& 2 & 1 & 5 & 3 & 4 \\
3& 3 & 4 & 1 & 5 & 2 \\
4& 4 & 5 & 2 & 1 & 3 \\
5& 5 & 3 & 4 & 2 & 1
\end{array}$$

I'm not sure how to separate the numbers further from themselves, so anyone please edit this. But as to my concern, I do not understand what's going on with this table. I cannot tell, by looking at tables, when it *is* or *isn't* a group.

Any insights?

Comment: I believe it is not associative.  Check (2*2)*3 versus 2*(2*3) for example

Comment: So from the table, what is (2*2)*3? This is where I run into problems because I'm not sure how to read the table.

Comment: I understood the table as follows: $x\cdot y$ can be calculated by finding $x$ down the left side and $y$ across the top and reading the corresponding element. For example, to compute $3\cdot 2$ I find 3 down the left column and $2$ across the top.  Then I see $4$ is the corresponding element between them.  On the other hand $2\cdot 3 = 5$.

Comment: Ahh yes now I see it. So 2*5 = 3?

Comment: If you happen to know that all groups of order $5$ are cyclic...

Comment: Hmmm... if all groups of order $5$ are cyclic, then the groups cannot commute?

Comment: 2*2=1 the identity. A group of order 5 can not have an element of order 2.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If it did define a group, it would have order five, but $2\times 2=1$, so the order of $2$ in the group is two, contradicting Lagrange's Theorem.